# Consuming Webservices Hosted on a WIFI Network via Windows Mobile Phone (.NET)

Tags: c#, web-services

Good Day,

I have created an asp.net web service on my local machine, and i can consume it with no problems using phone emulator but whenever tried to access it using a real mobile phone connected on my wifi network i can't access it, knowing that my localmachine (webservice hosted) and mobile phone (consumer) is connected on the same router. my question is is there any settings that I have missed?

I can access the webservice through emulator using this way :
http://192.168.1.101:55345/Webservice_Consume I've tried the same URL on my device and it fails.

I Hope someone could help me, and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things you should try:

1. Temporarily disable the firewall of
   web service host.
2. I believe 55345 is the port that
   built-in ASP.NET web server
   Visual Studio is using. Have you try to
   deploy the web application to IIS
   and access it from normal HTTP port
   (80) instead?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a mobile device (real or emulated) attached to your PC via activesync - by default pass-through networking is enabled, and your mobile device is given an IP in the AutoIP range. Your PC provides NAT/Routing for the mobile device.

That's how it should work when its behaving normally.

There really isnt enough info to answer this question. You can use the ASP.NET host app that's just fine. Try accessing it with pass-through networking enabled, and your device attached via USB.